# Autocompletion stopped working in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: vb.net

I'm a retiree trying to work VB.net for an app for a class in college.

Autocompletion stopped working in Visual Studio 2019. A Google search finds dozens of remedies. Most irrelevant (something about "Unity"). None of which fixed my issue.

I uninstalled and re-installed Visual Studio 2019.  Not fixed.

I repaired to reset to default settings.  Not fixed.

One suggestion appeared promising... Delete all the files in C:\Users\MikeW\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_04f9dab1\something or other...  Worked exactly once!

[image]

Should show MsgBox

Costing several hours in productive time.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you simply been creating a new project and choosing `Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)`?

Comment: Yes. .NET Core 3.1 (Long-term support).  Also tried .NET 5.0 (Current).  Same failure.

Comment: `MsgBox` is legacy VB6 code, which is runnable in a .NET Framework project. You're using .NET Core. While I haven't used it myself, I can almost guess that legacy VB6 code isn't supported. You should use the .NET version of `MessageBox.Show()`

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention if this is for one project, or all of them?

you could try this:

```
View => Solution Explorer (in case it isn't already open)
Right click "Solution 'Project name'"
Click "Open Folder in File Explorer"
Close Visual Studio
Show hidden folders in windows, and then:
Delete folder ".vs"
```

Comment: It's happening on all projects, old or new. I had tried this before based on Google results with no luck. Tried again. Again, no luck.

Comment: and you tried this: Go to Tools->Options->Text Editor-> All Languages->General Enable "Auto List Members" and "Parameter Information" Now "Restart the Visual Studio" and Try Again

Comment: Yes... done that multiple times. It's always checked. I even unchecked it, saved it, then checked it and saved, again. This is frustrating and puzzling. Costing tons of time.

Comment: I get this now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just to check: Have you been following some guides to remove telemetry? In that case, one of those guides break Intellisense and Spellchecking (which include autocomplete).

In that case, this folder *need* to exist and should not be removed:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\VSFeedbackIntelliCodeLogs
```

If it doesn't exist, you get the exact symptoms as described in your post, tab completion does not work (Intellisense)

Also, if you're having problems with functionality and you get a pile of big yellow stripes with warnings on top (which include the Intellisense warning and more), try running an update (Help/Check for updates...)

Comment: I've no idea what removing telemetry means, but that folder does exist and has dozens of text files in it.

Answer (score 0):

You reach this dialog from the Tools menu. Choose Options...

[image]

See if the your box more or less matches mine.

Comment: Okay!!  That worked, except this time instead of "Windows Form App", I used "Windows Form App (.NET Framework)".  I think someone else above tried to get me to understand that too!  Thank you!!